# Editing a search view in Django

Tags: django, search, django-forms, django-views

Hello I am working in django how to use a search form from Django documents site. Here are some information below.
Now, is there a way I can produce a part search for title? For example if I wanted to search for a book called "Apress", But instead of typing the whole word I just wrote "ap" to get Apress. Is there a way how to achieve this solution?

```
    from django.db.models import Q
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from models import Book

    #views.py
    def search(request):
        query = request.GET.get('q', '')
        if query:
            qset = (
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(authors__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(authors__last_name__icontains=query)
            )
            results = Book.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
        else:
            results = []
        return render_to_response("books/search.html", {
            "results": results,
            "query": query
        })

    #search html

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search{% if query %} Results{% endif %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Search</h1>
      <form action="." method="GET">
        <label for="q">Search: </label>
        <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ query|escape }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </form>

      {% if query %}
        <h2>Results for "{{ query|escape }}":</h2>

        {% if results %}
          <ul>
          {% for book in results %}
            <li>{{ book|escape }}</l1>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% else %}
          <p>No books found</p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Nothing, but I want to perform part searches. For example if I wanted to look for a title of a book called "Harry Potter", I want to be able just type in "ha" or "har" or otherwise to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match on the beginning of a field, you can use `startswith` or `istartswith` if you want it to be case sensitive. `icontains` which you are using now will allow matches even within strings, ie. 'arry' will match 'Harry'. While `startswith` will allow 'Har' to match 'Harry', but not 'ArHarHar'

Comment: Yes this what I was looking for thanks. If I was using numbers rather than normal characters would it work with startswith as well or something else. Let me explain an example. Suppose if I wanted to search for a number "1200" but I only wanted to type "12" to get "1200".

Comment: If the field is a character field and you are searching for the string "12" instead of the number 12, then yes it would work. However, if the field is an integer field of some sort I do not know if using startswith will work, probably not.

Comment: Yes, that it what I said, because if there is an integer field that would probably not work. The only thing I can think of is hard code through the views to be able to do that, but that may be too complex.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you store it as an integer in the database, if you want to use it(ie. do searches) like a string?

Comment: This example that I have done yesterday. It was really an example following Django documentation website. Just really wanted to build my skills so in the future to perform partial search for a number in an IntegerField. From your previous comment, it does not look like there is an easy way.